# Cannot transfer images received from FTP client onto my FTP server

Tags: c++, ftp

Using the below code, I'm able to read and store text files sent by FTP clients to my FTP server just fine, but images and other binary data ends up being corrupted.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something [in the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt). Is the error obvious?

```
    //open the file sepcified for output
    std::ofstream stor_file(cmd_arg, std::ios::binary);

    unsigned buf_size = 500;
    unsigned char *buf = new unsigned char[ buf_size ];

    const char *open_conn = "150 openeing data connection\r\n";
    CNetwork::write_to_socket( cntl_fd, open_conn, strlen(open_conn) );

    // slurp the whole file from the socket 
    int bytes_read = read( data_fd, buf, buf_size);

    while (bytes_read > 0)
    {
        // write what's in the buffer to the file
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes_read; ++i)
        {
            stor_file << buf[i];
        }

        memset( buf, 0, sizeof( buf ) );
        bytes_read = read( data_fd, buf, sizeof( buf ));
    }

    delete [] buf;

    // done writing...close the file!
    stor_file.close();

    // write to socket: "226 File successfully transferred\r\n";
```

Comment: If binaries are corrupt its usually a problem of the transfer type. Did your client sent the type to I (binary) before transferring the files? Do you distinguish between types A and I at all?

Comment: Since this is binary output, do yourself a favor and break the habit of using the stream-insertion operator. Just use.`stor_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), bytes_read)` and lose the for-loop. The memset is useless, btw, and personally I think either a fixed buffer or a `std::vector<>` would be a cleaner solution. And one last thing, `sizeof( buf )` is definitely wrong unless you intended to only read `sizeof(unsigned char*)` bytes for each go-around after the first.